# Upload a photo with some parameters to a Ruby-on-rails web app using Objective-C and an ASIFormDataRequest for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ios, asihttprequest, passenger

I need to upload a list of photos (can be one at a time) to my client's server from an iOS app (iOS 4). His server is using the Phusion Passenger 2.2.14 module on Apache Server (Ubuntu) to deploy his Ruby app.

Here is the Ruby code my client used to upload a photo using a Ruby rest client and it worked for one image. He mentonned that the image should be in an array but since here we are only sending one image, it worked.

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'http://serveraddress.com/id.json', :user => '********', :password => '*****'

resource.put :property => {:new_images => {:public => '0',:t_viewable => '0', :l_viewable => '0', :name => 'name3', :room => 'Bathroom', :attachment_type => 'periodic', :attached_file => File.new('/Users/me/Pictures/12618298.jpg','rb')} }
```

My question is, how should I encode this data using Objective-C collections?
Authentication works fine.

Here is the code I am using, but it gets a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
[request setPostValue:photoName forKey:@"property[new_images][0][name]"];

[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"property[new_images][0][created_at]"];

[request setFile:photoPathFull withFileName:[self.localCaptions objectAtIndex:index] andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
          forKey:@"property[new_images][0][attached_file]"];

[request setPostValue:self.room forKey:@"property[new_images][0][room]"];

[request setPostValue:imageCategory forKey:@"property[new_images][0][attachment_type]"];

[request setPostValue:public forKey:@"property[new_images][0][public]"];
[request setPostValue:tViewable forKey:@"property[new_images][0][t_viewable]"];
[request setPostValue:lViewable forKey:@"property[new_images][0][l_viewable]"];
```

*Note that the request variable is an ASIFormDataRequest object.

He also specified the server expects the following parameters:

```
property[new_images][1][name]=Sink
property[new_images][1][created_at]=<timestamp>
property[new_images][1][attached_file]=<filedata>
property[new_images][1][room]=Kitchen 
property[new_images][1][attachment_type]=periodic
property[new_images][1][public]=0
property[new_images][1][t_viewable]=0
property[new_images][1][l_viewable]=0
```

Thanks,

---

I finally got access to the errors log on the server side, so here is what it looks like:

---

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: 0

```
{"format"=>"json",
 "property"=>
  {"new_images"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"tenant_viewable"=>"0",
       "name"=>"photo2011-10-01 08:43:07 +0000.jpg",
       "landlord_viewable"=>"0",
       "attached_file"=>"#<File:0xda0361c>",
       "created_at"=>"1317459424.523741",
       "attachment_type"=>"periodic_check",
       "public"=>"0",
       "room"=>"Kitchen"}}},
 "action"=>"update",
 "id"=>"866",
 "controller"=>"properties"}
```

Action   properties#update

URL http://server.com/000.json

File    [GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:2587

---

It seems clear now that the attribute 0 (after attribute "new_images") is not expected from the server. Seems like it's more of an array position than an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do it for one image at a time you need to set the full property key value

```
[request setPostValue:@"Sink" forKey:@"property[new_images][1][name]"];
[request setPostValue:<timestamp> forKey:@"property[new_images][1][created_at]"];
....
```

Tedious, but I'm not sure you can set the single key `property` using an NSDictionary directly.  Dont think ASI is that smart.

To do it for an array, just enumerate through your array of images and set the `[1]` portion of the request key name to the actual index (e.g. [1], [2], [3], etc...)

I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the code and tried again. However, I still get a 500 internal server error. Any idea? I will ask the guy to send me the server log for this request.

Comment: I will accept your answer since the code that finally worked is very similar to what you posted. I just had to **remove the [1]** to see the photo uploaded. This format was one of the first I tried, but since I did not have access to the errors log on the server side, I didn't know that the error was all about this array [0],[1], etc. However, I think the server should accept this format... I will now have to figure out how to send an array of photos. I could also simply make a queue and PUT the photos one by one. May be easier to know which photos were really uploaded. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

ASIHTTPRequest can't automatically do a conversion of an array to a HTTP POST like that.

Try using ASIFormDataRequest instead:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Upload a file on disk
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

You'll probably have to experiment to some extent to figure out exactly the right format. I've advise using charlesproxy to compare the requests send by your working ruby code and the non-working iOS code on the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The request in my code is already an ASIFormDataRequest. I just edited to mention that.
About Charles Proxy, it would be handy to use it instead of NSLogging the request's attributes (responseHeaders, etc.).
Not sure if my question was clear enough, since I'd rather need to know how to setup the parameters as they are in the ruby code.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, but I do know about ASIHTTPRequest - if you look with charlesproxy at what is the raw text being sent to the server in each case, and tell us exactly how your iOS & ruby versions differ then we can tell you how to change the iOS one to make it work. NSLogging doesn't help, unfortunately - I've found comparing the an actual working request (as captured by charlesproxy, wireshark, etc) to a non-working one is the easiest way to figure out how to fix the non-working one.

Comment: Yes, NSLogging doesn't help much.... Hopefully, I could finally have access to the errors log on the server side, so it's much easier to debug. I am adding the error summary to the question now.